# Allocating the Sub items to the main Items in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for pandas/python solution to summarize/group items in an invoice, based on it's main code.
please refer the first attached image

[image]

each item value (price X qty) which has a MainCode should be added to the the item # total. Look for the Similar color. (Please Note some items may be repeated. eg : Green & Blue ) Qty SHOULD NOT be added. only the Values.

[image]

The answer should be as as follows
[image]

I'm New to Pandas & Since This is a bit Advanced problem, I couldn't come up with any code. hence, posted here. please direct me to solve this...

Things to note

1. Item combination can be repeated. eg see Green & Blue
2. Once Done Sub items should be removed (eg item # 371 is removed).
3. totalamt should equal to the total of individual item's price X Qty
4. In this example all sub item codes are 371. but it may have several codes. eg 371, 58, etc
5. Sub Item 371 can be sold separately without a MainCode. In that case, it should not be allocated & it should remain.

UPDATED DATA
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you enjoy it. Next time please provide input data not as images but as text.

```
import pandas as pd

data_raw = [[260, 1500, 3, 0, 4500], [260, 1500, 1, 0, 1500], [258, 1500, 4, 0, 6000], [1054, 1200, 1, 0, 1200],
[371, 700, 3, 260, 2100], [371, 700, 1, 260, 700], [371, 700, 1, 1054, 700], [371, 700, 4, 258, 2800]]

 data = pd.DataFrame(data_raw, columns=['item', 'price', 'qty','Main code','Total'])

remove_index= []
for index, row in data.iterrows():
     try:
         # find item in Main code
         main_code_data = data.loc[data['Main code'] == row['item']]
         # merge values
         data.at[index, 'Total'] = row['Total'] + row['qty']* (main_code_data['Total'].values[0]/main_code_data['qty'].values[0])
         # get indexes to remove
         for item in main_code_data.index:
            remove_index.append(item)
     except:
         # if no match
         pass

 # remove used lines
 data = data.drop(remove_index)
```

Output:

```
   item  price  qty  Main code  Total
0   260   1500    3          0   6600
1   260   1500    1          0   2200
2   258   1500    4          0   8800
3  1054   1200    1          0   1900
```

Comment: Thanks lot @Zaraki. Your answer is awesome. Really appreciate this.. There's one point i want to highlight, I'm not getting the correct Answer when there are duplicate/repetitive situation. refer my example color coded in GREEN & BLUE. (point # 1 in Things to Note section). In this situation, I'm not  getting the desired output. how can i solve this?

Comment: @Rapto you need to change index selection for values to select one element and add loop to collect all indexes. Code updated. Enjoy =^..^=

Comment: Thank you for the update. the updated code actually adds the first entry only. in the above example it works perfectly well. coz. both in the GREEN & BLUE lines, Item 260 has the same qty 3. i made a blunder in my data. in the BLUE line, i wanted to mention that the item repeats but qty may differ. example in GREEN line qty 3 for item 260 & in BLUE qty 1. similarly corresponding Item # 371 has 3 & 1 qty respectively. this should be the correct data.

Comment: so here, do we need to remove the used lines as and when we add the data? rather than waiting until the loop ends. `# remove used lines` `data = data.drop(remove_index)`

Comment: @Rapto Don't know exactly what you need? Provide proper start data and desired output.

Comment: I updated the original question (see UPDATED DATA section). sorry I don't know how to add the text data in proper table format. hence, I attached an image.

Comment: Thanks a million..This is what I wanted. Great job.!

Comment: Need your assistance on my [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57629485/speeding-up-pandas-code-by-replacing-iterrows) also mate.